# How to add markup inside a form radio button div

Tags: forms, theming

Currently I have a form displaying radio buttons and I added some markup to it by attaching #suffix to the form element. However, I found that this didn't do exactly what I needed. This created the following code structure:

```
<div class='field-wrapper'>
  <div class='radio-button-group-wrapper>
     ...
      <div class='radio-button-group-inner-wrapper'>
          <div class='radio-button'>
            <input type='radio'></input>
            <label></label>
          </div>
          <div class='radio-button'>
            <input type='radio'></input>
            <label></label>
          </div>
      </div>
 </div>
 <div>Markup goes here</div>  
</div>
```

I'm trying to figure out how to add markup inside the 'radio-button' div, right after the label tag. How can I do this? If there is no Drupal way of doing it, I can add it with javascript, but that's not ideal.

EDIT:
I have chosen to try using a custom template for this form element, but its not working. Here is my code:

```
'my_module_is_member_radios' => array(
  'variables' => array(
    'description' => array(),
  ),
   'template' => 'templates/my_module_is_member_radios',
),
```

Comment: theme_form_element_label

Comment: I would solve this problem by using the #theme tag to specify a custom theme function or template. You'll need to implement hook_theme() to declare it. Then you can output whatever HTML you like.

Comment: @AlfredArmstrong - can you provide an example of how to use the #theme tag? I have created theme templates before and used them to them content for pages and blocks, but I've controlled the input parameters there. What parameters are available in the template so that I can theme it?

Comment: You get passed in the element array from the form. If it's a field then the array is pretty complex. I'd install the devel module and use the dpm() function to dump it.

Comment: @AlfredArmstrong - I've got the theme in place and did a dpm($element), and its empty. I know the theme is being picked up, because I added placeholder text and its printing. Whats the exact name of the variables?

Comment: It's $variables['element'] assuming $variables is what you call the variables array being passed.

Comment: I found that I do have a $variables array, but it does not contain an 'element' subarray. I'm including the code for the creation of hte template. Do I need to do it differently? Perhaps with 'render element'?

Comment: Not sure what you get if you use a template rather than a function. Everything should be in $variables, anyway.

Comment: Ok - instead of setting 'variables' in the hook_theme, I set 'render element' => 'form'. I now saw all of the form info in $variables['form']. but don't see any 'element' array. I see all of the markup for this field, but I don't know how to render it. I tried drupal_render($variables['form']), but it messes up the page and prints this template file bunch of times. How do you render the element?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to follow @Alfred's advice above and used the #theme element to make this work.
I added this to my module theme hook:

```
'my_module_is_member_radios' => array(
  'render element' => 'form',
  'template' => 'templates/my_module_is_member_radios',
),
```

and in the template used this:

```
$armedForcedInfo = "some markup";
$civilianInfo = "some more markup"

$variables['form'][0]['#suffix'] = $armedForcedInfo;
$variables['form'][1]['#suffix'] = $civilianInfo;
print drupal_render($variables['form'][0]);
print drupal_render($variables['form'][1]);
```